# Can I use variables that are inside functions outside them?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, fivem

```
async function players_online() {
    const response = await fetch("http://ip:port/dynamic.json");
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data.clients);

    }
```

Can i use **data** inside other function? Exemple:

```
async function players() {
console.log(data.clients);
}
```

When i do this i recive **undefined**

Comment: no. you would have to return `data` and then pass it into `players`. See [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) on scope

Comment: If you want to have a global variable you'd need to define it as such. Having a variable scoped to a function means that it only exists within that function

Comment: You should have received an error, not undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Yes", you can:

```js
let data 

async function players_online() {
    const response = await fetch("http://ip:port/dynamic.json");
    data = await response.json();
}

async function players() {
    // You can't ensure data is already set!!!
    console.log(data.clients);
}
```

However you can not ensure that data is already defined at that point. You have to ensure by your own code that `players_online` is called and awaited before you call `players`.

You can ensure this with a call order like that:

```js
async function players_online() {
    const response = await fetch("http://ip:port/dynamic.json");
    const data = await response.json();
    await players(data)
}

async function players(data) {
    console.log(data.clients);
}
```